# Dealing with JSON Twitter Data

Tags: python, json, twitter

I would like to read multiple JSON files that contain data I have **scraped**. From those files I only want a particular key,value pair (tweet text). Since I have multiple files, I would like to extract all the text fields and store them in a CSV file containing column Tweet Text.

Please note each file contains one piece of data, I'd like to put them all together in a CSV file.

Following is a glimpse of what the JSON data looks like:

```
{
    "nbr_favorite": X,
    "is_reply": XX,
    "user_id": "XXXXX",
    "usernameTweet": "XXXXXX",
    "text": "XXXXXX",
    "nbr_retweet": XX,
    "nbr_reply": X,
    "datetime": "XXXXXX",
    "url": "XXXXXX",
    "ID": "XXXXXX",
    "is_retweet": XXX
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: that is not data from the Twitter API, how did you get that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) to parse the JSON file containing the response from the Twitter API to a python dictionary, following which you can retrieve the elements you're looking for, in this case `"text"`:

`response.json`:

```
{
    "nbr_favorite": 1,
    "is_reply": 12,
    "user_id": "XXXXX",
    "usernameTweet": "XXXXXX",
    "text": "My first tweet",
    "nbr_retweet": 1,
    "nbr_reply": 1,
    "datetime": "XXXXXX",
    "url": "XXXXXX",
    "ID": "XXXXXX",
    "is_retweet": true
}
```

```
import json

with open("response.json") as fh:
    json_dict = json.load(fh)
print(json_dict["text"])
```

Outputs:

```
"My first tweet"
```

You can loop over your JSON files to write the tweet text to a CSV file:

```
import csv
import json

response_files = ["response.json"]
with open("output_file.csv", "w") as csv_fh:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_fh)

    for response_file in response_files:
        with open(response_file) as fh:
            json_dict = json.load(fh)

        writer.writerow([json_dict["user_id"], json_dict["text"]])
```